# Ada constraint error: Discriminant check failed. What does this mean?

Tags: ada, spark-ada

I've tried searching the docs and the code, but I'm unable to find what this is and therefore how to correct it.

Scenario:

I'm using the Ada SPARK vectors library and I have the following code:

```
package MyPackage
  with SPARK_Mode => On
is
  package New_Vectors is new Formal_Vectors (Index_Type => test, Element_Type => My_Element.Object);
type Object is private;
private

   type Object is
      record
         Data : New_Vectors.Vector (Block_Vectors.Last_Count);
         Identifier : Identifier_Range;
      end record;
```

I get the error when the code calls:

```
function Make (Identifier : Identifier_Range) return Object is
   begin
      return (
              Data => New_Vectors.Empty_Vector,
              Identifier => Identifier);
   end Make;
```

Pointing to `Empty_Vector`. The difficulty is that `Empty_Vector` defines the `Capacity` as `0` which appears to be leading to the problem. Now I'm not sure then how to deal with that as `Capacity` seems to be in the type definition (having looked in `a-cofove.ads`).

So basically I'm stuck as to how to resolve this; or quite how to spot this happening in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The error occurs because you attempt to assign an empty vector (i.e. a vector with capacity 0) to a vector with capacity `Block_Vectors.Last_Count` (which appears to be non-zero).

You actually do not need to initialize the vector explicitly in order to use it. A default initialization (using `<>`, see, for example, [here](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/more_about_types.html#aggregates-a-primer)) suffices as shown in de example below.

However, in order to prove the absence of runtime errors, you *do* need to explicitly clear the vector using `Clear`. The `Empty_Vector` function can then be used to in assertions that check if a vector is empty or not as shown in the example below. The example can be shown to be free of runtime errors using `gnatprove`. For example by opening the prove settings via menu SPARK > Prove in GNAT Studio, selecting "Report checks moved" in the "General" section (top left) and then running the analysis by selecting "Execute" (bottom right).

**main.adb**

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Formal_Vectors;

procedure Main with SPARK_Mode is
      
   package My_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Formal_Vectors 
     (Index_Type   => Natural, 
      Element_Type => Integer);
   use My_Vectors;
   
   type Object is record
      Data  : Vector (Capacity => 10);   --  Max. # of elements: 10
      Value : Integer;
   end record;
   
   --  Initialize with default value (i.e. <>), no explicit initialization needed.
   Obj : Object :=
     (Data  => <>,
      Value => 42);
   
begin
   
   --  Clear the vector, required for the assertions to be proven.
   Clear (Obj.Data);
         
   --  Assert that the vector is not empty.
   pragma Assert (Obj.Data = Empty_Vector);
      
   --  Populate the vector with some elements.
   Append (Obj.Data, 4);
   Append (Obj.Data, 5);
   Append (Obj.Data, 6);
   
   --  Assert that the vector is populated.
   pragma Assert (Obj.Data /= Empty_Vector);
      
   --  Show the contents of Obj.Data.
   Put_Line ("Contents of Obj.Data:");
   for I in Natural range 0 .. Natural (Length (Obj.Data)) - 1 loop
      Put_Line ("[" & I'Image & "]" & Element (Obj.Data, I)'Image);
   end loop;
   New_Line;
   
   --  or, alternatively using an iterator ...   
   declare
      I : Extended_Index := Iter_First (Obj.Data);
   begin
      while Iter_Has_Element (Obj.Data, I) loop
         Put_Line ("[" & I'Image & "]" & Element (Obj.Data, I)'Image);
         I := Iter_Next (Obj.Data, I);
      end loop;
   end;
   New_Line;
   
   --  Show the contents of Obj.Value.
   Put_Line ("Contents of Obj.Value:");
   Put_Line (Obj.Value'Image);
   New_Line;   
   
end Main;
```

**output**

```
Contents of Obj.Data:
[ 0] 4
[ 1] 5
[ 2] 6

[ 0] 4
[ 1] 5
[ 2] 6

Contents of Obj.Value:
 42
```